# Why is $h_n(1,x,\ldots,x^{m}) = h_m(1,x,\ldots,x^{n})$?

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, symmetric-polynomials

Let $h_n$ denote the degree $n$ symmetric polynomial corresponding to the homogeneous basis. That is, in, e.g., $m$ variables

$$
h_n(x_1,\ldots,x_m) = \sum_{1\le i_1\le \cdots \le i_n \le m} \prod_{j\le n} x_{i_j}
$$

Why is the following identity in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ true?

$$
h_n(1,x,\ldots,x^m) = h_m(1,x,\ldots,x^n)
$$

I am interested in this because its equivalent to Hermite reciprocity of representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$: $\text{Sym}^n(\text{Sym}^m(V)) \cong \text{Sym}^m(\text{Sym}^n(V))$ for $V$ the standard representation.

Comment: Are you looking for a proof or a motivation? A proof can be found, e.g., in [A. Elashvili, M. Jibladze, D. Pataraia, *Combinatorics of Necklaces and "Hermite Reciprocity"*, Journal of Algebraic Combinatorics **10** (1999), pp. 173--188](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/JACO/Volume10_2/mm37q07u0p6u7703.fulltext.pdf).

Comment: yeah a proof. This is an exercise in Fulton and Harris, I'm looking for what is hopefully the clean idea to prove it. Thank you for the reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a partition $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_k)$ with $\lambda_1\geq \lambda_2\geq\cdots\geq\lambda_k$, write $x^\lambda=x_{\lambda_1}x_{\lambda_2}\cdots x_{\lambda_k}$. Then, with this notation, 
$$h_n(x_1,\ldots,x_m)=\sum_{\lambda\in X(n,m)} x^\lambda$$
where $X(n,m)$ is the set of partitions with $n$ parts of size $\leq m$, and
$$h_n(1,x_1,\ldots,x_m)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}h_k(x_1,\ldots,x_m)=\sum_{\lambda\in\bigcup_{k=0}^nX(k,m)}x^\lambda
$$
Similarly,
$$
h_m(1,x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{\lambda\in \bigcup_{k=0}^m X(k,n)} x^\lambda.
$$
Note that the transpose map $\lambda\to\lambda^t$ defines a bijection $\bigcup_{k=0}^mX(k,n)\to \bigcup_{k=0}^nX(k,m)$.

Now, for $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_k)$, set $|\lambda|=\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_k$ and note that $|\lambda|=|\lambda^t|$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
h_n(1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^m)&=\sum_{\lambda\in \bigcup_{k=0}^nX(k,m)} x^{|\lambda|}\\
&=\sum_{\lambda\in \bigcup_{k=0}^mX({k,n})}x^{|\lambda^t|}\\
&=\sum_{\lambda\in \bigcup_{k=0}^mX({k,n})}x^{|\lambda|}\\
&=h_m(1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^{n}).
\end{align}